# Error: The reference fst was not found in the current environment

Tags: coq

I am writing a small program so that I can work some proofs of deMorgans laws using the type introduction/elimination rules from the HoTT book (et. al.). My model/example code is all here, https://mdnahas.github.io/doc/Reading_HoTT_in_Coq.pdf. So far I have,

```
Definition idmap {A:Type} (x:A) : A := x.

Inductive prod (A B:Type) : Type := pair : A -> B -> @prod A B.

Notation "x * y" := (prod x y) : type_scope.

Notation "x , y" := (pair _ _ x y) (at level 10).

Section projections.
  Context {A : Type} {B : Type}.
  Definition fst (p: A * B ) :=
    match p with
      | (x , y) => x
    end.

  Definition snd (p:A * B ) :=
    match p with
      | (x , y) => y
    end.
End projections.

Inductive sum (A B : Type ) : Type :=
  | inl : A -> sum A B
  | inr : B -> sum A B.

Arguments inl {A B} _ , [A] B _.
Arguments inr {A B} _ , A [B].

Notation "x + y" := (sum x y) : type_scope.

Inductive Empty_set:Set :=.

Inductive unit:Set := tt:unit.

Definition Empty := Empty_set.
Definition Unit := unit.

Definition not (A:Type) : Type := A -> Empty.
Notation "~ x" := (not x) : type_scope.

Variables X:Type.
Variables Y:Type.

Goal (X * Y) -> (not X + not Y).
intro h. fst h.
```

Now I don't really know what the problem is. I've examples of people using definitions, but they always involve "Compute" commands, and I want to apply the rule fst to h to get x:X, so they are not helpful.

I tried "apply fst." which got me

```
Error: Cannot infer the implicit parameter B of fst whose type is
"Type" in environment:
h : A * B
```

Answer (score 3):

In a proof context, Coq expects to get *tactics* to execute, not expressions to evaluate.  Since `fst` is not defined as a tactic, it will give `Error: The reference fst was not found in the current environment.`

One possible tactic to execute along the lines of what you seem to be trying to do is `set`:

```
set (x := fst h).
```

Answer (score 3):

> I want to apply the rule fst to h to get x:X

I believe you can do

```
apply fst in h.
```

If you just write `apply fst`, Coq will apply the `fst` rule to the goal, rather than to `h`.  If you write `fst h`, as Daniel says in his answer, Coq will attempt to run the `fst` tactic, which does not exist.  In addition to Daniel's `set` solution, which will change the goal if `fst h` appears in it (and this may or may not be what you want), the following also work:

```
pose (fst h) as x. (* adds x := fst h to the context *)
pose proof (fst h) as x. (* adds opaque x : X to the context, justified by the term fst h *)
destruct h as [x y]. (* adds x : X and y : Y to the context, and replaces h with pair x y everywhere *)
```